# onPostExecute возвращает null

Tags: android, null, android-asynctask

doInBackground возвращает ответ с сервера. А вот onPostExecute этого ответа не получает и возвращает null.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

import eu.amirs.JSON;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MyAsyncRequest {
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://";

    private Context mContext;
    protected JSON jsResponse;

    //==============================================================================

    public MyAsyncRequest(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    // возвращает json-ответ
    public JSON response(String sRequest) {
        new AsyncRequest().execute(sRequest);
        return jsResponse;
    }

    public class AsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSON> {
        private ProgressDialog pd;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // включил progressDialog
            pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            pd.setMessage("Пожалуйста подождите");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSON doInBackground(String... strings) {
            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();                               
            RequestBody body;                                                         
            Request request;                                                      
            Response response;                                                                          
            JSON jsonResponse = null;                                                                   

            try {
                body = RequestBody.create(JSON, strings[0]);
                request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(SERVER_URL)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                jsonResponse = new JSON(response.body().string());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            client.connectionPool().evictAll(); 
            //тут json с сервера есть
            Log.d("ml", "doInBackground: " + jsonResponse.toString());

            return jsonResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSON json) {
            if (pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }            
            jsResponse = json;
            // а тут уже равен null
            Log.d("ml", "onPostExecute: " + json.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `// возвращает json-ответ` - при первом вызове метод `response` вернёт `null`, втором и т.д. - результат прошлого запроса. Потому что асинхронная задача выполняется не немедленно и её результат не может быть получен сразу после запуска. Видимо в этом у Вас и проблема. Нужно добавить какой-нибудь `callback` и в `onPostExecute` вызывать и передавать через него результат в вызывающий код. Но тогда проще сразу использовать асинхронный запрос c коллбэком (`enqeue` вместо `execute`) и не городить свой велосипед.

Comment: @woesss, просто я хочу все это сделать именно в стороннем классе, чтоб потом буквально в пару строк делать запрос на сервер. Enqueue в стороннем классе, странно себя ведет. На onresponse не дает сохранить результат в переменную

Comment: Тут без вариантов - либо всё делать в фоне и стучаться к UI через `Handler`, либо использовать обратный вызов, он же коллбэк. Какую переменную он не даёт изменить, локальную наверное (объявленную внутри метода) - так должно быть, в анонимах можно изменять только поля и свои собственные переменные. Но опять же вы делаете не то - нельзя в главном потоке сделать `JSON json = response(request);` - так Вы можете только получить уже загруженные до этого данные. Можно запустить запрос, передав ему коллбэк : `response(request, callback);` и продолжать работу с результатом в методе коллбэка